# Can i access the tailwind "last-child" property on a child of the last child?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an unordered list. I want to append the word "and" at the end of each item, except the last.

```
<ul className="ml-4">
  {
    categories.map((category, Idx) => (
        <li key={category.id} className="last:text-red-400">
         {category.description} <span className="last:hidden">; AND</span>
        </li>
    )
  }
</ul>
```

Actual output:

```
Red
Blue
Green
```

Desired output:

```
Red; AND
Blue; AND
Green
```

The "last" decorator on the "text-red-400" works. It was just for testing.
The one for "hidden" doesn't do what I want. All the "AND" s are hidden, presumably because they are all actually the last child of each of the li items, so the decorator is always active(?).

My current solution is

```
<ul className="ml-4">
  {
    categories.map((category, Idx, arr) => (
        <li key={category.id}>
         {category.description} <span className={`${Idx == arr.length - 1 && "hidden"}`}>; AND</span>
        </li>
    )
  }
</ul>
```

But i wondered if there was a better way apply the class so that only the word "and" on the last child of ul is hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```html
<ul class="ml-4">
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>span]:hidden">Blue <span>; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>span]:hidden">Green <span>; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>span]:hidden">Red <span>; AND</span></li>
</ul>
```

If there are multiple spans inside an `li`, you can specify something like this:

```html
<ul class="ml-4">
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>.foo]:hidden">Blue <span class="foo">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>.foo]:hidden">Green <span class="foo">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 [&:last-child>.foo]:hidden">Red <span class="foo">; AND</span></li>
</ul>
```

Another solution might be to use groups:

```html
<ul class="ml-4">
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group">Blue <span class="group-last:hidden">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group">Green <span class="group-last:hidden">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group">Red <span class="group-last:hidden">; AND</span></li>
</ul>
```

If there are nested groups (i.e. one of the parents already has group), you can name them:

```html
<ul class="ml-4">
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group/foo">Blue <span class="group-last/foo:hidden">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group/foo">Green <span class="group-last/foo:hidden">; AND</span></li>
  <li class="last:text-red-400 group/foo">Red <span class="group-last/foo:hidden">; AND</span></li>
</ul>
```

Feel free to change it to JSX. Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/XqG11h8pWD

Comment: Thanks - I wasn't really aware of the "group" classes. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution by tailwind but the same result

Adding a condition on the `; AND` span

```
{Idx < categories.length - 1 && (
  <span>; AND</span>
)}
```

```
import React from 'react';

const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    description: 'Red',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    description: 'Blue',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    description: 'Green',
  },
];

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <ul className='ml-4'>
        {categories.map((category, Idx) => (
          <li key={category.id} className='last:text-red-400'>
            {category.description}{' '}
            {Idx < categories.length - 1 && (
              <span>; AND</span>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```